# Pronoun with metaphor

Tags: pronouns, metaphors

Which pronoun do we use when referring to something metaphorically rather than directly?

[Todd Leopold](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/05/28/us/maya-angelou-obit/), et al., May 28, 2014 writing on CNN:

> A **literary voice** revered globally for **her** poetic command and **her** commitment to civil rights has fallen silent.

I would think one might use the pronoun corresponding to the metaphor *literary voice* (***it***) here, rather than the personality it refers to (***her***).

Especially as it somehow seems interfering with the subsequent *has fallen silent*.

Comment: The voice did not have a commitment to civil rights; the person did.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So?

Comment: You might want to give a little more context...is this about Maya Angelou? She is definitely a 'her' and so the voice wasn't ... never mind...what @JanusBahsJacquet said.

Comment: Look up *synecdoche*. Angelou is here being personified by her voice, one aspect of her as a human being. If one were making reference to *her* literary voice, then voice would be a literal reference and *it* would be appropriate. But that is not the case.

Comment: People get narky when a person gets referred to by 'it', even if indirectly.

Comment: @Mitch The link is very much there. Any issues with it?

Comment: @Robusto Yes, "but that is not the case."

Comment: @Neil True. However, my question is purely technical.

Comment: "Any issues with it"? Yes, a link is great but things fall apart or go behind paywalls or take extra work. Make it easier for the reader, include just a minimal amount of context.

Comment: @Mitch The broader context is not relevant to the technical question as you must have noticed already.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this deserves downvoting.

The whole question of the use of metaphor/s is very complex. When a vehicle is simply given as a different term for the tenor ('John is a tiger') there is little problem with syntax and other compositional requirements (though Jill may prefer to be labelled a tigress).

However, switching back from metaphorical to non-metaphorical language mid-sentence is certainly not without problems:

> (She was a literary voice that was heard over all the anglophone world
>   and beyond, compelling in its stridency, and selling more novels than
>   all her competitors.)

It is obviously unsatisfactory to switch between tenor and vehicle willy-nilly.

That having been said, with dead or near-dead metaphors which aren't extended (as with 'literary voice'), the tenor/vehicle swap is probably best treated as being a choice between synonyms, with the more fitting agreement being chosen (here, 'her').

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you may be talking about this article here http://ktla.com/2014/05/28/maya-angelou-dies-at-86/, right?

As you can see, the title is "Maya Angelou, Acclaimed Poet and Author, Dies at 86" and the first sentence of the article is the one you mentioned above: *A literary voice revered globally for her poetic command and her commitment to civil rights has fallen silent*. In this sentence, *her* refers to Maya, not to her voice. Just like @JanusBahsJacquet said, Maya was the one who had commitment to civil rights, which is a thing that a voice by itself can't do.